# Including patches to Build Root

Tags: linux, patch, buildroot

I tried to include my custom helloword patch to build root.

in

> make menuconfig

I have added global patch directory `/home/Downloads/buildroot/buildroot-2017.11/patches`

[image]

and I place my patch files inside the below directory

> (/home/Downloads/buildroot/buildroot-2017.11/patches/packagename/version/patch).

I referred [this link](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_within_buildroot) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382986/how-to-apply-patches-to-a-package-in-buildroot?rq=1)

After **make** command the patch is not getting applied in my source directory, the source is getting extracted to the output/build directory from the .tar fle.
please suggest a solution..

**Config.in**

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_HELLOWORLD
bool "helloworld"
help
  Hello World package says hello world to you
  see http://helloworld.com for more on this software
```

**helloworld.mk**

```
HELLOWORLD_VERSION = 1.0.0
HELLOWORLD_SOURCE = helloworld-1.1.tar.gz
HELLOWORLD_PATCH = 18-helloworld-testing.patch
HELLOWORLD_SITE_METHOD = local

define  HELLOWORLD_BUILD_CMDS
    $(MAKE) $(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS) -C $(@D)
endef

define  HELLOWORLD_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    $(INSTALL) -D -m 0755 $(@D)/helloworld $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/bin/helloworld

    $(INSTALL) -D -m 0755 $(@D)/helloworld-init $(TARGET_DIR)/etc/init.d/S90helloworld  
endef


$(eval $(generic-package))
```

Comment: I guess your patch is in `/home/Downloads/buildroot/buildroot-2017.11/patches/helloworld/1.0.0/0001-some-patch-description.patch`, and not in `/home/Downloads/buildroot/buildroot-2017.11/patches/packagename/version/patch` like you put in the question?

Comment: Yes, i just give general format, actually path is /home/Downloads/buildroot/buildroot-2017.11/patches/helloworld/1.0.0/

Comment: And it is called `something.patch`? Just `patch` is not going to work, it needs to end in `.patch`.

Comment: Just to be sure: you did do `rm -rf output/build/helloworld*` before calling make, right? Patches are not re-applied except when you completely remove the build directory.

Answer (score 0):

With the `local` _SITE_METHOD, patches are not applied. `local` is when you want to use the files directly from their source directory. With the `local` _SITE_METHOD, the directory specified in `HELLOWORLD_SITE` will be copied to the build directory, no patches are applied, the _SOURCE is not used.

However, since you don't specify `HELLOWORLD_SITE`, you trigger a corner case that causes it to behave like the `file` _SITE_METHOD (which is the one you actually want). Buildroot should give an error for this case. A [patch is pending](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/916192/) for this.

Unfortunately, that doesn't explain why the patches don't get applied.